# What is the best way to implement file upload using spring boot in AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, spring-boot-test

Working on Java Spring boot application(Web Service using web starter), I have requirement to store images in S3 bucket, Can someone suggest me how to implement?

Hosting application in EC2 instance

Comment: :D thanks @ErwinBolwidt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution
Refer below blog to implement Spring boot AWS s3 upload Image and delete image.

Link [Spring boot s3 upload](https://medium.com/oril/uploading-files-to-aws-s3-bucket-using-spring-boot-483fcb6f8646)

Answer (score 0):

you can use spring-cloud-aws with a s3 capable ResourceLoader:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context/spring-cloud-aws-context.xsd">
    <aws-context:context-credentials>
       <!-- ... -->
     </aws-context:context-credentials>
    <aws-context:context-resource-loader/>
</beans>
```

And inject it into your bean:

```
public class SimpleResourceLoadingBean {

@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

public void writeResource() throws IOException {
        Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource("s3://myBucket/rootFile.log");
        WritableResource writableResource = (WritableResource) resource;
        try (OutputStream outputStream = writableResource.getOutputStream()) {
            outputStream.write("test".getBytes());
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can find the documentation:
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/1.2.1.RELEASE/#_uploading_files

Comment: Just be aware that this will not work with S3 Server Side Encryption (SSE) because it's not possible to modify the metadata for the upload. Thus, this solution is restrictive.